# Prove $H_j(\mathbb{D}^n,\mathbb{S}^{n-1})\cong H_{j-1}(\mathbb{S}^{n-1})$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Consider the space $(\mathbb{D}^n,\mathbb{S}^{n-1})$ of topological spaces, $n>1$. Why is the reduced $j$th homology of this pair isomorphic to the $j-1$th homology of $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$, $j>1$, i.e. $H_j(\mathbb{D}^n,\mathbb{S}^{n-1})\cong H_{j-1}(\mathbb{S}^{n-1})$?

I tried to use the long exact sequence $$\cdots\rightarrow H_j(\mathbb{S}^{n-1})\rightarrow H_j(\mathbb{D}^n)\rightarrow H_j(\mathbb{D}^n,\mathbb{S}^{n-1})\rightarrow H_{j-1}(\mathbb{S}^{n-1})\rightarrow H_{j-1}{(\mathbb{D}^n)}\rightarrow\cdots$$

Can I conclude anything out of this? Why is the homomorphism $H_j(\mathbb{D}^n,\mathbb{S}^{n-1})\rightarrow H_{j-1}(\mathbb{S}^{n-1})$ an isomorphism?

Comment: Since $D^n$ is contractible, $H_j(D^n) = 0$ if $j\neq 0$, hence you get exact sequences of the form $0\to H_j({D}^n,{S}^{n-1})\stackrel{\partial} \rightarrow H_{j-1}({S}^{n-1})\to 0$ that show the boundary map is an isomorphism.

Comment: Right, thank you very much! And why do I need $n>1$?